# Which APIs should be used for enforcement of device and user policies on Chrome OS?

Tags: android, mdm, google-chrome-os

I'm looking for API resources (Chrome user and device policies) for managing **Chrome OS** mdm. It would be nice if I can get some references.
I have successfully managed the android mobile devices using **Android Managment API**. Now can't figure out about chrome OS. Any kind of suggestions and references or guidence would be appreciated.
Thank u in advance

Comment: stack overflow doesn't answer questions asking for references or off-site resources such as guides or tutorials, however, you could maybe edit your question to try and show what you've done and what you're struggling with so people could instead try to help you with that

Comment: actually i just need some suggestions from experts nothing else